# Bulk Insert into tables with many-to-many relationship with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a table of employees. Each employee can discuss certain products of the company with customers, i.e. we have a many-to-many relationship between employees and products. The schema is the following:

```py
metadata_obj = MetaData()

cv_calls_table = Table(
    "employee",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String),
    Column("key_id", String, nullable=True),
)

cv_products_table = Table(
    "products",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("product", String),
)

call_has_product_table = Table(
    "employee_has_product",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("employee_id", Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id")),
    Column("product_id", Integer, ForeignKey("products.id")),
)
```

Assuming that I have a csv file with, say, a million rows, of the following form:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Name      | key_id    | product  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| John Doe  | xyz       |pears     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| John Doe  | xyz       |apples    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Ann Smith | abc       |oranges   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Ann Smith | abc       |apples    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

What would be the best way to perform a bulk insert into my Database with the use of Pandas (for reading the csv file) and SQLAlchemy?
Inserting the employee and product data into the tables is no problem. I am struggling to find a neat way to insert the primary keys of employee and fruit into the junction table `call_has_product_table` .

I am using a SQLite Database.

I have tried using the SQLAlchemy ORM, but it seems that adding elements to a relationship can be only done individually for each employee, which is not feasible in terms of performance. I have therefore tried to set up the database with the Core. The code I used with ORM approach was

```py
#keep only data of employees
employees = employee_data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name','key_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

with Session(engine) as session:
    emply = []
    for i in employees.index:
        
        #Access each employee
        employee_row = employees.iloc[i,:]
        
        #Create the corresponding object
        employee_ = Employee(name = employee_row['Name'], key_id = employee_data['key_id'])

        #Get products associated to currently selected employee
        prods_ = employee_data.loc[(employee_data.Name == employee_row['Name']) & (employee_data.key_id == employee_row['key_id']), 'Product'].to_list()
        
        #Create corresponding Product objects
        products_ = [Product(product = prod_) for prod_ in prods_]
        
        #Add product objects to current employee
        employee_.products.extend(products_ )
        
        emply.append(employee_)
        
    session.add_all(emply)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

where `employee_data` is the Pandas dataframe of the form of the above table.

I could also solve the issue with Pandas by selecting the `id`'s of `employee` and `products` but I think there should be a better way, only using the capabilities of SQLAlchemy (or perhaps pure SQL).

Comment: _adding elements to a relationship can be only done individually for each employee, which is not feasible in terms of performance_
As long as you don't commit the session, the DB is not updated. Why is this a problem to update relationships individually if it does not trigger individual queries?

Comment: @DurandA I tried it and ended up crashing JupyterLab. It seemed to me that the problem arises because, in contrast to when bulk inserts are performed, a individual SQL statement is emmited for each object added to the session (in my case approximately 250.000).

Comment: Could you share the code you tried to insert the data?

Comment: @DurandA I have edited the question and added the code

Comment: "a individual SQL statement is emmited for each object added to the session" - Not necessarily. You can use `engine.echo = True` to inspect the INSERT statements that SQLAlchemy is emitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert `employee` and `products` to create records then select all records to get the (auto-generated) primary keys. Merge them on the `employee_data` dataframe then populate your last table:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine, Engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData, Table, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.types import String, Integer

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
metadata_obj = MetaData()

# Your table declaration here

metadata_obj.create_all(engine)

employee_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv').rename(columns={'Name': 'name'})

with engine.connect() as con:
    # Employees
    employees = employee_data[['name','key_id']].drop_duplicates()
    con.execute(cv_calls_table.insert().values(employees.to_dict('records')))
    
    # Products
    products = employee_data[['product']].drop_duplicates()
    con.execute(cv_products_table.insert().values(products.to_dict('records')))

    con.commit()
    
    # Get Primary Keys
    tbl1 = pd.DataFrame(con.execute(cv_calls_table.select()).all()).rename(columns={'id': 'employee_id'})
    tbl2 = pd.DataFrame(con.execute(cv_products_table.select()).all()).rename(columns={'id': 'product_id'})

    employee_data = employee_data.merge(tbl1, on=['name', 'key_id'])
    employee_data = employee_data.merge(tbl2, on='product')
    
    # Employee / Product
    con.execute(call_has_product_table.insert().values(employee_data[['employee_id', 'product_id']].to_dict('records')))
    con.commit()
```

Output:

```
>>> employee_data
        name key_id  product  employee_id  product_id
0   John Doe    xyz    pears            1           1
1   John Doe    xyz   apples            1           2
2  Ann Smith    abc   apples            2           2
3  Ann Smith    abc  oranges            2           3
```

Check with Pandas:

```
con = engine.connect()

>>> pd.read_sql_table('employee', con)
   id       name key_id
0   1   John Doe    xyz
1   2  Ann Smith    abc

>>> pd.read_sql_table('products', con)
   id  product
0   1    pears
1   2   apples
2   3  oranges

>>> pd.read_sql_table('employee_has_product', con)
   employee_id  product_id
0            1           1
1            1           2
2            2           2
3            2           3
```